# Public key problem when updating

Tags: 12.04

When I try to start the update manager, and install updates, I get this error:

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages. This action would require the installation of packages from unauthenticated sources.
```

It then gives a load of libraries   (I think?) that cannot be updated. They all seem to be linked to the GIS software QGIS.

If I try to do: sudo apt-get update . Then it scrolls through a load of messages, ending with this:

```
W: GPG error: http://qgis.org precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be     verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BBA6491F47765B75
```

So I did some searching and tried this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys BBBA6491F47765B75
```

However I then get the error:

```
gph: requesting key 47765B75 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Connection refused
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: cojudln't connect: connection refused
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
gpg: Total numner processed: 0
```

I'd appreciate ideas on what to do about this please.

Best wishes

James